# What is the logical form of this sentence using a truth table?

Tags: logic

How do I properly determine the logical form of the sentence (A*B) > (~A > ~B) using a truth table?

Comment: What do you mean by 'modal nature'?

Comment: What is it's logical form? I suspect it is a contradiction, but I am trying to be sure for when the exam comes.

Comment: Do you know how to construct a truth table for this sentence though? or do you need help with that?

Comment: I need help with a truth table, it is my weakest point in logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth table:

```
A  B  A*B  ~A>~B  (A*B)>(~A>~B)
===============================
T  T   T     T         T
T  F   F     T         T
F  T   F     F         T
F  F   F     T         T
```

The sentence is a tautology.